# bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `../../assets/images/background.png` from `src\IntroScreen\IntroScreen.js`

Tags: react-native

how to solve this error?

bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `../../assets/images/background.png` from `src\IntroScreen\IntroScreen.js`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check this folder with your explorer yourProject/assets/images/background.png is there any background.png exist ?

Comment: ithink i dont have file background.png
let me try this

Comment: Yeah try it, that error is very clearly show background.png is nothing there

Comment: Yes. I just spent 2 Hours trying to debug what went wrong and found out that that file was opening in the browser with different name. So i renamed the file and it worked. Please try to avoid special charecters like space and so on. It it works fine. Thanks @RahmadAlHabib

Answer (score 0):

It's because maybe in the background your server was running and you dragged the image or folder into the assets folder while running the server. Since the newly added file address hasn't been stacked to memory or you can say the background hasn't been noted you already copied the image. So it throws this error.

So now you close the server then you restart it again or rerun npm then the server or interpreter will note that and put it on memory. Then you will not see this error.